# Using jQuery, how do i return an object from a function for use within the scope of current function?

Tags: jquery, function, return

This is the code I have (so far). I have had success with directly alerting the values from the large image url. I want to be able to return the values as an object to another variable but have had no success. What am I doing wrong?

```
$.fn.extend({
        getBgImage: function(callback){
            var path = $(this).css('background-image').replace('url', '').replace('(', '').replace(')', '').replace('"', '').replace('"', '');
            var tempImg = $('<img />');
            tempImg.hide(); //hide image
            tempImg.bind('load', callback());
            $('body').append(tempImg); // add to DOM before </body>
            tempImg.attr('src', path);
            $('#tempImg').remove(); //remove from DOM
        },
        jZoom: function(){
            var swide = $(this).children('.zimg').outerWidth(),
                shigh = $(this).children('.zimg').outerHeight(),
                large = $(this).attr('href');
            $(this).after('<div class="mousearea" style="width:'+swide+'px;height:'+shigh+'px;cursor:move;z-index:99;opacity:0;position:absolute;top:0;left:0;"></div>').parent('.zoom').after('<div class="large" style="background-image:url('+large+');"></div>');
            var limg = $(this).parent('.zoom').next('.large').getBgImage(function(){
                var y = $(this).height(), x = $(this).width();
                alert(x+' '+y); // this alerts the values as expected
                //return {x: x, x: y}; This is what I attempted to return the values
            });
//alert(limg.x); and this is where i check to see if the object are available but get undefined
        }
    });
    $(function(){
        $('.zoomme').each(function(){
            $(this).jZoom();
        });
    });
```

This is just a work in progress, mainly for the sake of doing it but would like to know where I have gone wrong so far.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are assigning the return value of the `bgImage` function, and not the return value of the function you are passing as an argument to `bgImage`.

Since the callback doesn't actually get executed when you pass it, and is instead bound as a load handler, there is no way to get its return value at that point.

Comment: Thanks for your pointers, I'll go see if I can do it another way.